# Why is this command not making class files double clickable?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, windows-registry, jvm

I wanted to make .class files open with java.exe when double clicked. First, I tried to do that using "open with", it did not even take java.exe as a choice. Now I entered the following in cmd -

```
reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\.class" /VE /D "classfile" /F 1>NUL
reg Add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\classfile\shell\Open\Command" /VE /D "\"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk8\bin\java.exe\" -cp \"%~p1\" \"%~n1\"" /F 1>NUL
```

Since this, whenever I click a .class file, a little window pops up with the text "could not find or load main class" with path to the class. The window quickly disappears.
I am using Windows 7.
Why is what I entered not doing the intended task?

Comment: does your .class file have a `public static void main(String[] args)` method?  java.exe won't run just any .class file.

Comment: yes, my class has that method

Comment: this is my class- public class H
{
 public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
 {
  System.out.println("hello world");
  Thread.sleep(100000);
 }
}

Comment: I compiled it and clicked on the class file, this is what came - Error: Could not find or load main class C:\Users\USER\Desktop\H.class

Comment: maybe change `%~n1` to `%~f1`?